# Plot median houseprice over last 10 years with large dataset in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset, median

I need to create a plot with the monthly median house price over time. The data is at a random order and consists selling prices of individual houses.

I already converted the daily dates to monthly and converted Value into a numeric column. But I can't manage to calculate the median per month.

```
below are the characteristics of the dataset.
  str(a)
'data.frame':   1411764 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date : Factor w/ 498 levels "1977-11","1978-06",..: 108 60 12 58 51 60 12 59 60 60 ...
$ Value: num  223000 171528 110269 172436 181512 ...
>head(a)    
    Date    Value
1  2003-01 223000.0
2  1999-01 171528.0
3  1992-01 110268.6
5  1998-11 172436.5
9  1998-04 181512.1
10 1999-01 197848.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `plyr` for this. Something like this should get you a `data.frame` with the median per month:

```
library(plyr)
result_df = ddply(a, .(Date), summarize, median_value = median(Value))
```

`plyr` is known to be a little slow for larger datasets, but I would just give the code above a try. A very good alternative is `data.table`, which provides roughly the same functionality, but then orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Also many thanks to you @Paul, I tried both answers and both worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of data, you will find `data.table` very efficient for such operations. If you don't, you will still find `data.table` very useful -

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,list(medianvalue = median(Value)), by = "Date"]
```

Comment: +1! It does make sense to simply use `data.table`, especially when you still have the choice and do not have experience using either `data.table` or `plyr`. I like the syntax of `plyr` better though ;).

Comment: Haha, that's just the opposite of my attitude. the first time I used R was with a really large dataset. I've been using `data.table` ever since and have stayed away from plyr, ddply, etc. I slip up when using data.frames sometimes even :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfect. Now I need to plot it with the dates at the x-axis, but this should not be a problem. Thanks!